# Can I use Yashica 35-70 and Canon 28-80 lenses on DSLR cameras?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-adapter, yashica

I have two camera lenses; one is a Yashica 35-70 mm lens which I am using on a Yashica FX-7 Super manual 35mm film camera. The other is a Canon 28-80 mm lens which came with the Canon EOS 66 35mm film camera.

Can I use either of these lenses on any of the popular DSLR cameras makes, like Canon, Nikon, Sony, or Panasonic?

Comment: The Canon aspect is already answered at [Can the lenses of a Canon EOS film camera be used on a digital one?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29154/can-the-lenses-of-a-canon-eos-film-camera-be-used-on-a-digital-one)

Comment: The question should be closed. The Canon aspect is answered at the question @mattdm linked, and the Yashika part is a duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62000/4262)

Answer (score 1):

If your lenses are for a Canon EOS they should be EF mount and they should work on Canon EOS dSLRs.

Answer (score 1):

Contax/Yashica mount lenses can be adapted to Sony E-mount (not A-mount) and Panasonic/Olympus micro four-thirds and other mirrorless cameras, as well as Canon EOS-mount dSLRs.  They cannot be adapted to Nikon F mount dSLRs with simple rings because of the flange distance issues, but you *might* be able to replace the mount with [a Leitax kit](http://www.leitax.com/Zeiss-Contax-lens-for-Nikon-cameras.html); however the cost will probably make just getting a native 18-55 kit lens more practical.  However, be aware you won't have aperture control from the camera, autofocus, you'll have to use stop-down metering, and there won't be any EXIF information from the lens. (See: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/))

Strangely, you're more restricted on the Canon EOS lens. Canon's EOS (EF) lenses can be used directly on their dSLRs, but adapting one to another brand of camera is more than problematic, because EOS lenses have no aperture ring, and without electronic communication, you have no control over aperture.  In this case, mirrorless mounts are only mounts you can adapt to with [an expensive Metabones adapter](http://www.metabones.com/products) that can "translate" the electronic signals between the body and the lens and allow for aperture control. But again, the cost may simply make going for a native equivalent lens more practical.

Personally, neither of those lenses is really worth the pain to adapting. They've got relatively small ranges, and slow max. apertures, and aren't a great fit for general walkaround use on a camera with an APS-C sensor (i.e., most mirrorless and entry-level dSLRs). An 18-55 kit lens is, on APS-C, a 28-80mm f/3.5-5.6 equivalent, and serves the same purpose your two lenses did on their respective bodies, and is really cheap if it comes with the kit.

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that the EOS lens can be fully functional on an EOS digital camera make it *less* restricted as long as an EOS body, which is included in the question, is used?

Comment: @MichaelClark my perspective was across the mount systems: as in, if you wanted to choose any camera and then adapt the lenses, the EOS would be more restrictive on your camera body choices.