# Can I use lenses from EOS-3 film camera with Canon EOS 7D?

Tags: canon, film, old-lenses, compatibility

Can I use lenses from EOS-3 film camera with Canon EOS 7D?

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61853/which-current-canon-aps-c-cameras-can-use-older-eos-ef-lenses/61856#61856

Comment: And: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29154/can-the-ef-lenses-of-a-canon-eos-film-camera-be-used-on-an-aps-c-digital-eos-cam

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those older Canon film lenses will be fully compatible with a new Canon digital camera as they both use the same EOS system and EF lens mount.

Many older lenses from 3rd party companies like Sigma and Tamron may not be compatible as  they were reverse engineered and can cause errors when used on the latest Canon cameras.

Answer (score 1):

If these are Canon EF lenses, then yes, they can.